# How can I use PostgreSQL's partial sum tree index (if it even exists)? Do any databases allow for use of such an index?

Tags: mysql, algorithm, mongodb, postgresql, tree

> GiST (Generalized Search Tree) indexing is an advanced system which brings together a wide array of different sorting and searching algorithms including B-tree, B+-tree, R-tree, **partial sum trees**, ranked B+-trees and many others.

http://www.postgresql.org/about/

Do partial sum trees have a synonymous phrase that will help me find more info on using such a tree as a table's index?

OR, do any databases (MySQL, MongoDB) have any customizability that allows for a person to cleanly implement a partial sum tree to use as a table's index? The index would need update operations that not only update a node's value but it's ancestor's values so that the index STAYS a partial sum tree.

Comment: What are you actually attempting to do? What problem are you trying to solve with this?

Comment: X-posted to http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/97764/7788

Comment: @Craig Ringer I need to do weighted random sampling. The weights change frequently. I researched it and a a partial sum tree as an index seems to be the best solution. Requiring the least writes while not taking up too much memory (like the Walker's alias method).